# Include custom folders using Christoc's Theme Template for DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke, skinning

I'm trying to build a DNN Skin with Christoc's Template and i need to include some new folders i created into the install zip.
I'm inserting this tag in SkinPackage.targets

```
 <InstallInclude Include="**\<FOLDER_NAME>\*.*" />
```

But when building the install zip, the folder is not being included.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have any contents/files in those folders?

Comment: Fixed! sorry i'm too new into this. Resources.zip included the files all this time... (feel so noob) Thank you anyway for your help Chris!